# PHP - catchall method in a class

Tags: php, oop, class, methods, catch-all

Is there away to set up a class so that if a method is not defined, instead of throwing an error it would go to a catch-all function?

such that if i call `$myClass->foobar();` but foobar was never set in the class definition, some other method will handle it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, it's [overloading](http://php.net/__call):

```
class Foo {
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        echo "$method is not defined";
    }
}

$a = new Foo;
$a->foo();
$b->bar();
```

As of PHP 5.3, you can also do it with static methods:

```
class Foo {
    static public function __callStatic($method, $args) {
        echo "$method is not defined";
    }
}

Foo::hello();
Foo::world();
```

Comment: +1 To add, it's *PHP* overloading, which is (inexplicably) a different use of the term than other OOP languages.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use [__call()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) to catch the called methods and their arguments.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use the [__call](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods) magic method which is invoked when no suitable method is found. Example:

```
class Foo {
    public function __call($name, $args) {
         printf("Call to %s intercepted. Arguments: %s", $name, print_r($args, true));
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->bar('baz'); // Call to bar intercepted. Arguments: string(3) 'baz'
```

Answer (score 1):

[Magic methods](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php). In particular, [__call()](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods).

Comment: __invoke is something different than __call.

Comment: __invoke would be the answer if @changokun would like to do `$myclass();`